# Unable to catch CKEditor change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I looked through many threads at SO, but could not find an answer that solves my problem. So, I define a CKEditor instance like so:

```
var editor = $('#test-editor');

editor.ckeditor(function() {}, {
  customConfig: '../../assets/js/custom/ckeditor_config.js',
  allowedContent: true
});
```

However I do not know how can I catch `change` event. This is what I tried:

```
var t = editor.ckeditor(function() {
  this.on('change', function () {
    console.log("test 1"); 
  });
}, {
  customConfig: '../../assets/js/custom/ckeditor_config.js',
  allowedContent: true
}); 

editor.on('change', function() {   
  console.log("test 2"); 
});

t.on('change', function() {   
  console.log("test 3"); 
});
```

All these three attempts ended in failure. I should add, that I do not want to loop through all editors on a page, I just want to address one particular editor rendered at component with `#test-editor`. How can I do that?

Comment: BTW, I see that my editor variable contains a promise Object. But I've never delt with them and I'm not sure how can I use this fact to catch the event,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery [ckeditor()](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR_Adapters.jQuery-method-ckeditor) method returns a jQuery object, which exposes only 5 events of CKEditor in its [event handling](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-event-handling). In order to use other events, you need to use the [CKEditor.editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor) object by accessing the [editor](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery-section-editor-instance) property of the jQuery object.

So, you need to use something like this:

```
var myeditor = $('#test-editor').ckeditor({
    customConfig: '../../assets/js/custom/ckeditor_config.js',
    allowedContent: true
});
myeditor.editor.on('change', function(evt) {
    console.log('change detected');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, probably you know one more thing about CKEditor. To me it looks like Format, Font and Size comboboxes occupy too much place on the toolbar. Do you know, if it is possible to change them to an icon or some custom letter?

Comment: I once changed their labels for fun, but the widths stayed the same (maybe because of the widths of their items).